# From Date, to Date Need to select only 7 days on selection

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have two text boxes With Calendar, I need to select a week from both text boxes,suppose I have selected 02/02/2017 in from date and I should able to select upto 09/02/2017 in to date beyond that is should not allow us to select. same is the scenario if i select in the last month if i select 01/01/2017 i need to select upto 08/01/2017. please help. tell me how to do it using jQuery or javascript or anything..

Answer (score 0):

"I have two text boxes With Calendar" What does that mean? Is the control that has the date a DateTimePicker? What? If it really is a textbox, use a datetimepicker, or some calendar control that has a MaxDate property.

If so, add an event handler to the datetimepicker's value changed event, that resets the MaxDate property on the control to one week after the date entered when a user changes the date.

Comment: It is a Date Time Picker, Can You Please help me with the code i am new to jQuery

Comment: My apologies, I was misled by your C# tag. The dateTime picker I am familiar with is a C# winforms control, the one you are using (it seems), is a JQuery control which I am not familiar with.  You should google the documentation for "JQuery DateTimePicker" and look for how to code an Event handler for the value changed, or perhaps the Click event and the Min and max date properties on the control.